# It is possible to compile less file to less with compression and without comments?

Tags: css, less

i have much more less files that are imported in a main.less file. Now i wanna to make a main.min.less file with imported files and compressed and without any comments. what command i used is:

```
lessc main.less > main.min.less -x
```

This command compress the file but can't remove the restricted comments(/*! comments */).
Keep in mind i wanna to make another .less file and not .css file. Any idea?

Comment: @DarshakShekhda: Seriously? A link to the same question? Did you post the wrong link?

Comment: For minifying use [`--clean-css`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-clean-css) instead of `-x`. Though you **can't** compress less to less with `lessc` (it's "Less Compiler" not "Less Minifier").

Comment: @seven-phases-max You're right. But I don't need a minified css version, the reason that i want to mifiying the less file, is performance. Is there any Less Minifier tool? I didn't worked with grunt, could it helpful?

Comment: If you really care about performance do not use client-side compilation. Precompile your Less to CSS offline/server-side. This is what the mainstream workflow is.

Comment: In our application, users should be able to change less variables through forms, And the less file should be immediately compiles to css. Is server side compilers able to respond to plenty and huge requests?

Comment: >In our application, users should be able to change less variables through forms - Then I'm afraid the only option for you is to forget about performance. After all I don't think minifying/concatenating Less input will significantly improve anything for client-side stuff.

Comment: by mistake i put wrong link above, now try this link http://cssminifier.com/

Answer (score 0):

Because of Less code is very similar to CSS code, you should be able to (re)use many methods of  for instance [clean-css](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/).

Create a file called `clean-less` and write down the following content into it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var path = require('path'), 
CommentsProcessor = require('clean-css/lib/text/comments'),
fs = require('fs');

var args = process.argv.slice(1);
var input = args[1];
if (input && input != '-') {
    input = path.resolve(process.cwd(), input);
}

var parseFile = function (e, data) {
var lineBreak = process.platform == 'win32' ? '\r\n' : '\n';
var commentsProcessor = new CommentsProcessor(0,false,lineBreak);

//single line comments
var regex = /\/\/ .*/;
data = data.replace(/\/{2,}.*/g,"");

/*
methods from clean css, see https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/
*/

var replace = function() {
    if (typeof arguments[0] == 'function')
      arguments[0]();
    else
      data = data.replace.apply(data, arguments);
};


//multi line comments 
replace(function escapeComments() {
    data = commentsProcessor.escape(data);
});

  // whitespace inside attribute selectors brackets
  replace(/\[([^\]]+)\]/g, function(match) {
    return match.replace(/\s/g, '');
  });

  // line breaks
  replace(/[\r]?\n/g, ' ');

  // multiple whitespace
  replace(/[\t ]+/g, ' ');

  // multiple semicolons (with optional whitespace)
  replace(/;[ ]?;+/g, ';');

  // multiple line breaks to one
  replace(/ (?:\r\n|\n)/g, lineBreak);
  replace(/(?:\r\n|\n)+/g, lineBreak);

  // remove spaces around selectors
  replace(/ ([+~>]) /g, '$1');

  // remove extra spaces inside content
  replace(/([!\(\{\}:;=,\n]) /g, '$1');
  replace(/ ([!\)\{\};=,\n])/g, '$1');
  replace(/(?:\r\n|\n)\}/g, '}');
  replace(/([\{;,])(?:\r\n|\n)/g, '$1');
  replace(/ :([^\{\};]+)([;}])/g, ':$1$2');


process.stdout.write(data);
}
if (input != '-') {
    fs.readFile(input, 'utf8', parseFile);
}
```

Than make the clean-less file executable on your system (`chmod +x clean-css`). 
You should probably also run `npm install path` and `npm install css`. After that you should be able to run:

```
./cleanless input.less > input-clean.less
```

The input-clean.less file will be some kind of minimized and not contain comments any more.

In the comments @seven-phases-max wonders if minifying reduces client side compile time. Well the client side compiler loads the Less files over a XMLHttpRequest. Reduce the number of bytes will give faster loading. I can not say that is a bottleneck or not.

When i try the above code with the navbar.less file from Bootstrap i found:

```
8.0K    navbar-clean.less
16K navbar.less
```